# Vim preferences

Tags: vim

I've searched high and low but cannot get the correct syntax etc. I'd like to set my `vim_rc` file so I'm using the evening theme and **16pt Lucida** console text as a default. I've tried many combinations and I am not having much joy on the web. At present, I'm receiving the following error:

```
 Error detected while processing C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Vim\_vimrc:

line   47:

E518: Unknown option: Console\ 14
```

and my vim file (based on web advice) looks like the following

```
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      if empty(&shellxquote)
        let l:shxq_sav = ''
        set shellxquote&
      endif
      let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  let cmd = substitute(cmd, '!', '\!', 'g')
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3
  if exists('l:shxq_sav')
    let &shellxquote=l:shxq_sav
  endif
endfunction
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set textwidth=80
set guifont=Lucida Console\ 14
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows10: \_gvimrc guifont settings not taking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427981/windows10-gvimrc-guifont-settings-not-taking-effect)

Comment: By the way, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim` is off limit. All your customisation is supposed to happen in `C:\Users\CB2100\vimfiles`. See [this document](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc) for more guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape spaces with a backslash. You've already done so for the space after "Console". You just need to also escape the one before "Console".

```
set guifont=Lucida\ Console\ 14
```

Comment: many thanks ive just done this however the font remains the same?

Answer (score 0):

in _vimrc file:

set guifont=Lucida_Console:h14